# Get values from each entry box through individual button for each box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I created Entry and buttons through a loop, like this

```
for i in range(len(headers)):
        pos_y = 0;

        e = tk.Entry(top, width = 30);
        e.grid(row = pos_x, column = pos_y);
        entry[i] = e;
        e.insert(0, headers[pos_x].get('name'));
        pos_y += 1;

        b = tk.Button(top, text = 'Copy');
        b.grid(row = pos_x, column = pos_y);
        button[i] = b;
        pos_y += 1;
```

I've two dicts for Entry and Button each, output is like this.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWXf.png)

What I want to do is for each of the buttons, I want to copy value from the textbox to clipboard.
I know how to copy to clipboard, just getting the corresponding value is the problem.
Edit:
Header is a list of dictionaries; pos_x is used to switch from one row to other; pos_y is used to switch to next coulmn.
Here I'm iteration over a dictionary to get names from dict to 1st textbox and values to another.
like this :{"name": "key", "value": "2500"}
button and entry are dicts, declared above as entry{} and button{}.

Comment: Please provide a testable example. Just looking at what you have now it looks like you are using a dictionary to store your variables and in that case you just need to call the appropriate key.

Comment: Testcase like what?

Comment: Please read the following and then formulate your question around it. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See there's a button for each textbox, so what I want to achieve is as I click the button next to the textbox, the text within gets copied to the clipboard.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but when asking a question you need to provide a testable example so we can formulate a proper answer. What you have shown now is incomplete. I do not have the content of `headers` or `pos_x` so I can only guess at your code and guessing is not the best approach to answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making things more complicated than they need to be. You do not need to place your buttons in a dict/list as you are not changing them after they are created.
Instead think about using a simple list to story your entry values and then use their index to call the get method on them when you need them.

Here is my example. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entry_list = []

        r = 0
        c = 0
        for i in range(6):
            self.entry_list.append(tk.Entry(self, width=30))
            self.entry_list[-1].grid(row=r, column=c)
            tk.Button(self, text='Copy', command=lambda ndex=i: self.copy_to_clipboard(ndex)).grid(row=r, column=c+1)
            if r == 2:
                c += 2
                r = 0
            else:
                r += 1

    def copy_to_clipboard(self, ndex):
        print(self.entry_list[ndex].get())
        self.clipboard_clear()
        self.clipboard_append(self.entry_list[ndex].get())

Example().mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I'm not well-versed in OOP.
Will it work for button clicks in any order?

Comment: @hellomunni the same logic can be used for non-OOP. Each button is only going to grab values from the entry it was assigned. So yes it works in any order. You could copy my example and see for yourself.

Comment: Why are you passing ndex into copy_to_clipboard() not i itself?
It worked anyway, many thanks.

Comment: @hellomunni because its the most efficient way of working within a list of widgets. As long as you generate each lambda expression correctly you can reference the position of the widget in a list and just perform the copy function based on that reference.

Comment: Okay, that helps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the entry reference to the command function of the corresponding button, like below:

```
def do_clipboard_copy(entry):
    text = entry.get() # get the entry content
    print(text)
    # do whatever you know to copy the entry content to clipboard

for i in range(len(headers)):
    row = i // 2
    col = (i % 2) * 2
    entry = Entry(top, width=30)
    entry.grid(row=row, column=col)
    entry.insert(0, headers[i].get('name'))
    Button(top, text='Copy', command=lambda e=entry: do_clipboard_copy(e)).grid(row=row, column=col+1)
```